# AWS Lambda Function with Chalice not handling SQS messages

Tags: python, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, chalice, aws-sqs-fifo

I have a lambda function which is implemented with Chalice and I am trying to process SQS messages with it.

The code is implemented based on this documentation:
https://aws.github.io/chalice/api.html#Chalice.on_sqs_message

`app.py`

```
app = Chalice(app_name='payment-service')

@app.on_sqs_message(queue="payment-service-dev.fifo")
def lambda_sqs_message(event):
    print("MESAGE QUEUE EVENT ", event)
    for record in event:
      print("Process Event")
    return True
```

The problem is that I am not receiving any logs from the `lambda_sqs_message` when the Lambda Function handler is set to `app.app`. However, it works if I set the Lambda Function handler to `app.lambda_sqs_message`.

Handler set to `app.app` - Queue events not processed
[image]

Handler set to `app.lambda_sqs_message` - Queue events are processed
[image]

I don't think that it makes any sense to have the the Lambda handler set to `lambda_sqs_message` because this way the `on_sqs_message` is useless.

Did I misunderstood the configuration requirements and the Lambda Function handler needs to be set to the SQS message handler function, instead of the Chalice instance?

Comment: So you mean with decorator `@app.lambda_sqs_message` it works but `app.on_sqs_message` does not work

Comment: It's working only if I configure the Lambda Function to have the handler set to `app.on_sqs_message` and I don't understand why it's not working while it's set to `app,app`

Comment: could you give 2 versions of code (1 work and 1 does not), that would be useful